# PHP MySQL Multiple Joins

Tags: php, mysql, join

Working on an application that needs to collaborate three tables.
Product Offers, Transactions, Declined Offers
In otherwords: (Available Products), (Purchased Products), (Products Declined, Not interested.)

Product Offers Contains All product data: (Name, Desc, Price, anything shown during the while script)

I don't want to show products if they have been purchased or declined.

For instance:

```
"Select * 
               JOIN Whatever
               JOIN Whatever
               (WHERE NOT IN PURCHASED OR DECLINED)";
```

I have a working code, for showing where not declined:

```
$products= "SELECT a.*, b.pID, b.userID, a.pID as pID FROM products a                   
                  LEFT JOIN declined_products b ON (a.pID = b.pID AND b.lenderID = '$userID')
                  WHERE b.pID is NULL AND b.userID is NULL
                  LIMIT $start, $maxres";
```

But when I try to add the second join, it no longer works... (maybe I'm using the wrong Join side? I am honestly new to joins.

```
$products= "SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*, a.pID as pID FROM products a                   
                  LEFT JOIN declined_products b ON (a.pID = b.pID AND                     b.lenderID = '$userID')
                  RIGHT JOIN p_transactions c ON (c.product = a.pID AND c.user_id = '$userID')
                  WHERE b.appID is NULL AND b.userID is NULL AND c.user_id <> '$userID' AND (`c.callback` != '1' or `c.callback` is NULL)
                  LIMIT $start, $maxres";
```

Comment: Ouch my eyes, sorry hard to read, try adding 4 spaces before the query, I fix one for you as an example.

Comment: To answer you seem to be missing the `ON` part of the join.  And a whole lot of other issues.

Comment: Id use `INNER JOIN` and fix this `a.`  a . what? `a.*`

Comment: Sorry about the code, its clean in my PHP file, this was my first time posting.

Comment: Basically here is the run down:   Select * Products Display in while loop -  Unless record in declined products (where product Id and user id match).  Or if purchased already (where product id/user id in purchased table)

Comment: I only want to display products where they don't have a declined record for that user, or a transaction for that user.

Comment: It's to many joins / variables for me to do it in my head without the tables and a database to test it in.  I cleaned it up a bit for you though.  99% of the time you wont need a right join.  The `a.` bit will give you a syntax error for sure.

Comment: Thank you @ArtisiticPhoenix for your help , it's 1am here and I've been pulling my hair out trying to understand these directions.

Comment: Why select pid twice !?!

Answer (score 0):

See something like this

```
$products= "
SELECT a.*,
    b.*,
    c.*,
    a.pID as pID
FROM
    products AS a
LEFT JOIN
    declined_products AS b ON (a.pID = b.pID AND b.lenderID = '$userID')
INNER JOIN
    p_transactions AS c ON (c.product = a.pID AND c.user_id = '$userID')
WHERE
        b.appID is NULL
    AND
        b.userID is NULL
    AND
        c.user_id <> '$userID'
    AND
        (c.callback != '1' or c.callback is NULL)
    LIMIT $start, $maxres
";
```

I won't get into sql injection but to say look into PDO query parameters,

By the way JOIN is the same as INNER JOIN, it just reads better IMO.  Hardly ever will you need to use a Right Join.  I added `AS` in for the same reason I like to use `INNER JOIN`.  Latter I will know it's intentional and not a typo.  Just more readable, but that is my Opinion 'as' it works either way.

Comment: I am going to run this and get back to you.